# Windows "repeat" on moving them

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, compiz, window-manager

With a second monitor connected via Displayport, I have the issue that windows repeat on my primary monitor (Lenovo ThinkPad T460p).

[image: Screenshot]

When I click on the desktop after dragging a window, the drawings dissappear.

My System:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.10 64 Bit
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8
- Graphics Card: GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing the recommended Nvidia driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Check for recommended drivers: `ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0 ==
model    : GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000134Dsv000017AAsd00005050bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-370 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-367 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-364 - third-party free
```

In my case it was `nvidia-370 - third-party free recommended`. So I've installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370 nvidia-prime
reboot
```